# Google Drive XLSX File not readable anymore (Rescuing corrupted file)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, encoding, xlsx

I had created a google sheets (xlsx file) for my studies and after I finished the studies, stored it on pcloud and deleted on Google Drive.
Upon trying to open it on pcloud, I just noticed, it's corrupted. pcloud claims there is a password protection, but there shouldn't (as I didn't set any).
So I asked my file to be restored from Google Drive (as it was already deleted permanently) and was able to get it restored. However it's also not openable there anymore.
Since the file still contains some mb of size and somewhat text (if I try to open with Visual Studio Code it contains what seems to me wrongly encoded), I am wondering if there is really no way to restore it somehow.
Please find attached an example of how the file looks in Texteditor:
[image: xlsx file]

If you have any idea how I could try to restore it, I would be thankful for any kind of help. (Pcloud and Google Support weren't)

I am using:
MAC OS Monterey
File was downloaded from Google Drive (Chrome & Safari tested)
Tried to open it with: Google Drive, Numbers (MAC), CotEditor, Visual Studio Code

Thank you and sorry!

Comment: Excel xlsx files cannot be read by a text editor. The internal format is a zipped folder with lots of other files inside, most of it XML. Can you open the file with a zip tool? Using Windows, I have manipulated xlsx files by creating a copy, then changing the extension from .xlsx to .zip. Then unzip the file and look at the components.

Comment: @teylyn Thanks for the tip! I tried with 2 zip tools, but was unsuccessful unfortunately. :/

Comment: What is the result when you try to upload to Google Drive?

Comment: @Emel thanks for the reply! it says it cannot be opened. It also says it would be password-protected, which doesn't make any sense, as I never set any password.

Comment: It's seems that the document is corrupted. Also, I can not understand the password problem, it doesn't make any sense to me. Have you tried opening it with Microsoft Excel? Just as a last try,

Comment: Hey @Emel exactly - (see original post) it's corrupted. however, since it is still containing data, I was wondering if it is somehow rescuable. :D I do not have microsoft excel unfortunately :(

Comment: There is not much that you can do from what I see. Inside Excel you have a tool for repairing a [corrupted workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53) also you have some online [alternatives](https://excel.recoverytoolbox.com/)(not tested and not sure if trustable).